# Chrome Extension : background.js works every X minutes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a background.js which will work every X seconds.
How can I set time interval for **background.js**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your background.js script file in your page, then call whatever functions it contains that you wish to use using [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function()
{
myFunc()
},2000);
```

The number at the end is the number of milliseconds gap and replace myFunc() with the name of the function you wish to call.

Answer (score 0):

from the [github page](https://github.com/kmalakoff/background):

```
queue = new Background.JobQueue(2000)
```

in that queue you add all the jobs you need, changing the timing in ms

with more info provided (see as "more code") we could help you more than this

Comment: This answer is not applicable to the [Chrome extension's background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html).